# rearranging from colum to row in a csv

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, perl

I have a CSV file that presently has an output like this

1

2

3

4

5

what I need to do is reconfigure the output as follows

1 2 3 4 5

all the entry data on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
echo $(<file.csv)
```

if the sample input is really like what you showed.